# How to remove "Values" and "series" from highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm using highcharts on my website, which looks great, but I now want to remove these two labels from the chart:
[image]

I tried disabling all sorts of labels, such as this one:

```
{
    title: {
        text: 'X axis labels are disabled'
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
}
```

but I can't find a way to remove these specifically.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-enabled/) of the image above.

Does anybody know how I can remove these labels?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The "Values" is the [title of the y-axis](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.title.text). It can be disabled like this:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: null
    }
}
```

or

```
yAxis: {
    title: false
}
```

The "Series 1" is part of the [legend](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend). It can be disabled like this:

```
legend: {
    enabled: false
}
```

Or alternatively disable a specific series from being shown in the legend, like this:

```
series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
}]
```

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhj3tda9/) for a live demonstration.

Comment: Awesome! The yAxis trick does the job, but unfortunately the code for disabling the legend doesn't work for me, probably because I'm using it with highcharts-ng: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng . Any idea how I can disable the legend with highcharts-ng?

Comment: @kramer65 I updated the answer with an alternative route for hiding a series in the legend. This method appears to work with Highcharts-ng (from my quick test).